# What is the convention for variable names in lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I see a lot of examples where for example

```
int sum = widgets.stream()
                  .filter(w -> w.getColor() == RED)
                  .mapToInt(w -> w.getWeight())
                  .sum();
```

can we use any variableName in these lambda expressions?

I thought variable names have conventions and is good to use proper names for readability.

For instance if I use w as Widget in pre-java8, the code would be shunned as not readable. What has changed with the advent of java 8?

```
   for(Widget w : widgets)
   {
         if(w.getColor() == RED) {
            sum += w.getWeight();
         }
    }
```

Why can't the code be written like this:

```
int sum = widgets.stream()
                  .filter(widget -> widget.getColor() == RED)
                  .mapToInt(widget -> widget.getWeight())
                  .sum();
```

Maybe the code above is doing something straight-forward, and only on widget in the list of widgets. So, something more:

Which is better readable:

```
    return  requestHolder.getRequests()
                        .stream()
                        .map(request -> request.getErrorHolder())
                        .flatMap(errorData -> errorData.getErrors().stream())
                        .collect(toList());
```

or

```
    return  requestHolder.getRequests()
                        .stream()
                        .map(t -> t.getErrorHolder())
                        .flatMap(r -> r.getErrors().stream())
                        .collect(toList());
```

Maybe I am missing something. Could you explain?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong with using `w` as the variable name in a foreach loop like that. It's perfectly clear what it is and why it's there. It's like using `i` as the counter in a `for` loop.

Comment: A method like `map` takes _each_ element and converts it. It doesn't really matter what you call the reference to the object.

Comment: I'd agree that it's like using `i` as a loop counter, but there may be situations in a lambda where it's not clear what a short name refers to, and using a longer name would be helpful.

Comment: @ajb: sure, and in these situations, it’s recommended to use a longer name. But that doesn’t imply that we should always use longer names. In the case of `.mapToInt(widget -> widget.getWeight())` most developers would even use `.mapToInt(Widget::getWeight)` because the parameter name really doesn’t matter…

Comment: Since you asked "can we use any variableName in these lambda expressions", I believe that a proper answer would include "no, you can't use a name that conflicts with the name of a local variable".  This means, for example, that if you're inside a loop `for (int i = ...)`, you can't also use `i` as a parameter name in a lambda expression.

Comment: @Holger Right, I didn't mean to imply that longer names should always be used.  I usually use short ones.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The tacit convention is: name your variables so the code is pleasant and easy to read.

In my opinion, a very short name or a dummy name is preferable when the scope of the variable is limited. It makes the code more readable, lighter and also indicates that the function of the variable is limited.

Explicit names are to be preferred when the variable is used extensively in the code and you want to avoid to have it confused with other variables.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < max ; ++i) {
    int myExplicitVar = myArray[i];
    // rest of the code using myExplicitVar several times
}
```

For lambdas, the scope of the variable is usually extremely limited and I find it easier to read when the name is short **so only the important parts of the code remains**, which was the point of lambda expressions in the first place.

In your examples, I find the short names more straight to the point.

Short variable name makes the code less bloated but can lead to confusions in rich contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm using Java8 for some time, and indeed I've found that I'm using longer names more often. My take on that is a simple rule of thumb: I like short name or not.

I usually go for short names like *i* or *y* if it's obvious what's happening inside of a stream. If you're processing a stream of widgets and doing a 4-6 operations, writing *widget* each time is annoying and lines start to look the same after couple of operations. So for stream of same things, where from context I easily know what I'm working on, I sometimes go for short variables. It's same as with the loop iterators, where everyone use *i* and not *index*.

On the other hand, if Im doing a lot of processing and especially if I need to map something, I like to give descriptive names, going even to extreme like *widget*, *filteredWidget*, *widgetHeight* etc.

As for common notation on the web, please remember that a lot of people try to promote new Java syntax. It's cool that it can be short so they tend to take it as far as possible. In Javaland we always had to write a lot, and my guess is that people overreact to the fact we can type less. Look for examples at Venkat S. talks about groovy or .js from 2 years back, he often undelrined how important it is that he does not have to type semicolon at the end of the line. That how our brain works I guess.